# Best practise for debbuging hdd

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, diagnostic

I just logged onto my machine when suddenly `ls` gave me an `Input/output` error. After rebooting the machine `/dev/sda1` could not be mounted.
`dmesg` results in :

```
[  545.691453] EXT4-fs (sda): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
```

and `parted -l`

```
Error: /dev/sda: unrecognised disk label
```

However smartmontools doesn't show me any problems

`smartctl -H  /dev/sda`

```
 SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
```

`smartctl -l selftest /dev/sda`

```
 # 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1152         -
```

How shall I proceed and is there a way to pin it down to a hardware or filesystem  problem?

Comment: S.M.A.R.T does not check filesystem errors it reports what the HDD firmware knows about its own health.  S.M.A.R.T can only detect problems it actual tracks.